# Automatic dialog height

Tags: html, css

I've subclassed YUI dialog (aka Overlay) such that it contains a title, an optional tool bar, a body and an optional footer. The dialog can also be re-sized by the user.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/isme/UbZbB/) that demonstrates this but the guts of it is as follows:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="hd"></div>
  <div class="tb"></div>
  <div class="bd"></div>
  <div class="ft"></div>
</div>
```

The rules I'm after are:

- outer minimum height is same as hd.height
- hd height is fixed
- tb, bd and ft are of variable height
- tb and ft should wrap
- tb and ft should be fully visible if possible at the expense of bd
- if there isn't enough space to show tb and ft fully, assign the remaining space evenly between the two and hide bd
- if bd is larger than the div that contains it, x/y overflow should be scroll

I've done this programmatically but there are some issues in IE 7 and 8 (all is a bit more complex than described here with padding, margins and borders further complicating matters) and only ever got this working cleanly in the latest versions of Chrome, FF and IE.

But somehow I feel like I'm missing something: browsers have powerful layout engines, so I probably just don't know enough about CSS and HTML to write my code such that the layout engine can do its job.

Can this be done using some CSS/HTML wizardry?